# C# Enumerations, Structs and Classes

Tags: c#, class, enumeration, struct

Could anyone just enlighten me on the main differences in C# between enumerations, structs and classes? I usually just use classes for this type of code but never really seen the need to use the others?

Comment: You need to ask a more focussed question.

Comment: I believe this question would help some beginners to take a general idea about the mentioned items. It could be usefull for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refering to :

[Introduction to Objects and Classes in C# - Introduction](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/C-Sharp/Introduction-to-Objects-and-Classes-in-C-sharp/1/)

[Introduction to Objects and Classes in C# - World's Classes and Objects](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/C-Sharp/Introduction-to-Objects-and-Classes-in-C-sharp/2/)

> In Object-Oriented Programming
>   programmers write independent parts of
>   a program called classes. Each class
>   represents a part of the program
>   functionality and these classes can be
>   assembled to form a program.
>
> In our world we have classes and
>   objects for those classes. Everything
>   in our world is considered to be an
>   object. For example, people are
>   objects, animals are objects too,
>   minerals are objects; everything in
>   the world is an object. Easy, right?
>   But what about classes?
>
> In our world we have to differentiate
>   between objects that we are living
>   with. So we must understand that there
>   are classifications (this is how they
>   get the name and the concepts of the
>   Class) for all of those objects. For
>   example, I'm an object, David is
>   object too, Maria is another object.
>   So we are from a people class (or
>   type). I have a dog called Ricky so
>   it's an object. My friend's dog, Doby,
>   is also an object so they are from a
>   Dogs class (or type).

A Struct is similiar to class with several differences.

Refering to [Structs](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/Lesson12.aspx)

> A struct is a value type. To help
>   understand the struct, it's helpful to
>   make a comparison with classes.  While
>   a struct is a value type, a class is a
>   reference type.  Value types hold
>   their value in memory where they are
>   declared, but reference types hold a
>   reference to an object in memory. If
>   you copy a struct, C# creates a new
>   copy of the object and assigns the
>   copy of the object to a separate
>   struct instance. However, if you copy
>   a class, C# creates a new copy of the
>   reference to the object and assigns
>   the copy of the reference to the
>   separate class instance. Structs can't
>   have destructors, but classes can have
>   destructors. Another difference
>   between a struct and class is that a
>   struct can't have implementation
>   inheritance, but a class can...

[Enumerations](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/lesson17.aspx) are essentially unique types that allow you to assign symbolic names to integral values.

Comment: Cheers, good to know that some people do not immediately dismiss an answer because it doesn't make sense to them, this is what I wanted, thanks Akram.

Comment: @Bali C: Some people follow the easy way - "sometimes" to be fair -:D

Answer (score 5):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ms348103) is a great reference: [Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b0thckt.aspx), [Enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138362.aspx), [Struct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/saxz13w4.aspx).

Comment: This would be a great comment, this does not answer the OP's (too broad) question.

Comment: I was just about to post those exact links :) +1

Comment: I think a subtly phrased RTFM is a great answer

Comment: I think this references in this answer describe the usage of the mentioned key words in C# and do not answer the question at all !!

Comment: @Akram, if you read the links, then you can easily see differences for yourself. Also, from the struct link: "Structs share most of the same syntax as classes, although structs are more limited than classes:..." and "How to: Know the Difference Between Passing a Struct and Passing a Class Reference to a Method (C# Programming Guide)"

Comment: @Akram, thanks, yeah, the links tell me the usage of the code, but my question was more along the lines of "Where would I use one over the other", which is why I posted the question here!

Comment: @Bali C: Check the other answer ..

Comment: @George Duckett: I believe you have earned 4 votes on "MSDN is a great reference" :P